# Rock, paper, scissors game php

Tags: php, session

So, I am creating a Rock, Paper, Scissor game in php. I am creating two webpages. The first webpage will contain three radio buttons for rock, paper, scissor and one submit button. The first page will send the information to the second page. The second page is the computer. The computer will randomly choose between rock, paper, scissor.

This is what I have right now. It is just not sending the information in the right way.

```html
FirstPage:

<?php
session_start();    //session start
  if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))     //if session not found redirect to homepage
  {
    header('location:login.php');
  }
    else{
      echo '<form action="game.php" method="post" />
            <input type="radio" name="user_choice" value="Rock" title="Rock" />Rock <br /><br />
            <input type="radio" name="user_choice" value="Paper" title="Paper" />Paper <br /><br />
            <input type="radio" name="user_choice" value="Scissors" title="Scissors" />Scissors <br /><br />
<input type="button" name="user_choice" value="Submit" title="Submit" /> <br /><br />
          
            </form> ';
          }
?>

SecondPage:

<?php
session_start();    //session start
//if session not found redirect to homepage
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('location:login.php');
} elseif {
    elseif($_POST['user_choice']) {
        $user_choice = $_POST['user_choice'];
        $Choosefrom= array(Rock, Paper, Scissors);
        $Choice= rand(0,2);
        $Computer=$Choosefrom[$Choice];
        elseif($user_choice == $Computer) {
            echo 'Player: '.$user_choice.' CPU: '.$Computer.'. Result: Win';
        } else {
            echo 'Player: '.$user_choice.' CPU: '.$Computer.'. Result: Lose';
        }
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: your form lacks a submit button

Comment: where is your submit button ? Please add the button .

Comment: I just add the submit button and still not working

Comment: "not working" tells us nothing. thats the wrong input type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code.
first page

```
<?php
session_start();    //session start
  if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))     //if session not found redirect to homepage
  {
    header('location:login.php');
  }
    else{
      echo '<form action="game.php" method="post" />
            <input type="radio" name="user_choice" value="Rock" title="Rock" />Rock <br /><br />
            <input type="radio" name="user_choice" value="Paper" title="Paper" />Paper <br /><br />
            <input type="radio" name="user_choice" value="Scissors" title="Scissors" />Scissors <br /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="form_submit" value="submit"/> 
            </form> ';
          }
?>
```

game.php page code

```
<?php
session_start();    //session start
//if session not found redirect to homepage
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('location:login.php');
} elseif {
    if($_POST['user_choice']) {
        $user_choice = $_POST['user_choice'];
        $Choosefrom= array('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors');
        $Choice= rand(0,2);
        $Computer=$Choosefrom[$Choice];
        if($user_choice == $Computer) {
            echo 'Player: '.$user_choice.' CPU: '.$Computer.'. Result: Win';
        } else {
            echo 'Player: '.$user_choice.' CPU: '.$Computer.'. Result: Lose';
        }
   }
}
?>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: it is not displaying the answer in the game.php.