# php game Rock, paper, scissors

Tags: php, session

So, I am creating a Rock, Paper, Scissor game in php. I am creating two webpages. The first webpage will contain three radio buttons for rock, paper, scissor and one submit button. The first page will send the information to the second page. The second page is the computer. The computer will randomly choose between rock, paper, scissor.

This is what I have right now. It is just not sending the information in the right way.

```html
First page:
<?php
session_start();    //session start
  if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))     //if session not found redirect to homepage
  {
    header('location:login.php');
  }
    else{
      echo '<form action="game.php" method="post" />
            <input type="radio" name="user_choice" value="Rock" title="Rock" />Rock <br /><br />
            <input type="radio" name="user_choice" value="Paper" title="Paper" />Paper <br /><br />
            <input type="radio" name="user_choice" value="Scissors" title="Scissors" />Scissors <br /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="form_submit" value="submit"/> 
            </form> ';
          }
?>

Second Page:
<?php
session_start();    //session start
//if session not found redirect to homepage
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('location:login.php');
} elseif {
    if($_POST['user_choice']) {
        $user_choice = $_POST['user_choice'];
        $Choosefrom= array('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors');
        $Choice= rand(0,2);
        $Computer=$Choosefrom[$Choice];
        if($user_choice == $Computer) {
            echo 'Player: '.$user_choice.' CPU: '.$Computer.'. Result: Win';
        } else {
            echo 'Player: '.$user_choice.' CPU: '.$Computer.'. Result: Lose';
        }
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: i thinks same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40602274/rock-paper-scissors-game-php

Comment: what is different in 2 question?

Comment: It should be closed.

Comment: if this answer in this question is wrong (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40602274/rock-paper-scissors-game-php). why this question is accepted?

Comment: please comment with english

Comment: @adri-abella-villafranca , check your php script under second Page : its wrong there .... having error in **elseif** condition

Comment: The question is a duplicate because it's identical, doesn't matter that it's a wrong answer. The question is identical.

Comment: @adri-abella-villafranca ,now have you any problem ?

Comment: @adri-abella-villafranca ,wait let me check whole script :)

Comment: What does this mean exactly: *"It is just not sending the information in the right way."*? What have you tried to troubleshoot this? There is a lot of reasons why this question should be closed.

Comment: @adri-abella-villafranca , how to genrate DRAW case , what is the conditon in which game called draw ?

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? Might help...`ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` Just trying to help you help yourself a bit.

Comment: @adri-abella-villafranca ,check my answer and try it once. (let me know if you have any query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Solved Game logic , try with this,*** (logic Maybe Helpful)

```
<html>
        <body>
            <?php
                error_reporting(E_ALL);
                session_start();

                $_SESSION['username'] = true;// to bypass Login page (remove it once you test it)

                if(!isset($_POST['user_choice'])){
                    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
                        header('location:login.php');
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "First page:";
                        $_SESSION['secondPage'] = true;
                        echo '<form action=htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); method="post" />
                        <input type="radio" name="user_choice" value="Rock" title="Rock" />Rock <br /><br />
                        <input type="radio" name="user_choice" value="Paper" title="Paper" />Paper <br /><br />
                        <input type="radio" name="user_choice" value="Scissors" title="Scissors" />Scissors <br /><br />
                        <input type="submit" name="form_submit" value="submit"/> 
                        </form> ';
                    }
                }
            ?>
            <?php
                if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
                    header('location:login.php');
                } else {
                    if(isset($_POST['user_choice'])) {
                        echo "Second Page:<br><br>";
                        $CPUChoice = array('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors');
                        shuffle($CPUChoice);
                        //echo "CPU Select". $CPUChoice[0];exit;

                        $CPU = $CPUChoice[0];
                        $User = $_POST['user_choice'];

                        echo 'Player: '.$User.' <br>CPU: '.$CPU;

                        if($User === $CPU){
                            echo '<br>Result: Tie!';
                        }
                        else if($User === "Rock"){
                            if($CPU === "Scissors") {
                                echo '<br>Result: User wins';
                            } else {
                                echo '<br>Result: CPU wins';
                            }
                        }
                        else if($User === "Paper") {
                            if($CPU === "Rock") {
                                echo '<br>Result: User wins';
                            }else {
                                if($CPU === "Scissors") {
                                    echo '<br>Result: Computer wins';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if($User === "Scissors") {
                            if($CPU === "Rock") {
                                echo '<br>Result: CPU wins';
                            } else {
                                if($CPU === "Paper") {
                                    echo '<br>Result: User wins';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                   }
                }
            ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```